# Insert data into SQL tables manually using the related columns in Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to insert data into some related table in SQL Server 2008R2 and I am trying to figure out whether there is an easier way to insert data manually (visually) using the related columns and not the IDs. If you check the two snapshots of the tables and table `WFUserGroup` basically I am trying to see if I can have a bound query (like in MS ACCESS) where I can see the `Name` column instead of the `ID` and the name of the Group instead of the `group_id`

I know that with a `TRANSACTION` block and `INSERT INTO` statements I can create a new user in `WFUser` table and then relate it to a group in the `WFUserGroup` table, but I am telling myself there should be an easier way. Anyone knows a workaround?

Tables:

[image]

Using Edit Top 200 Rows Feature:

[image]

Comment: Write a stored procedure to accept 2 parameters, `Group Name` and `User Name`, then insert the connecting table ID's based on the parameters.

Comment: I realized with VIEWS we can insert new data or modify data and the change would be reflected back to the tables, but still, we should enter the data manually and there could be some typos etc that can cause problems if there was a way that SSMS could create a drop-down or something it could be awesome, ACCESS can do this easily

Comment: Short answer - no, SSMS does not have any such in-built feature. SSMS is not really designed to be a data-entry tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a flat file with data in a .csv or excel and use the Import feature in SQL server.

how to navigate, right click on the database and tasks--> Import then the wizard to select the necessary file and tables.

I do see that there are primary key and foreign keys so you have to make sure that its considered in your files you are going to import.

[image]

Comment: this does not solve the problem since in the Excel file one has to use the IDs and not the names pulled from another table. I am trying not to look for the IDs manually and let SSMS take care of that

Comment: then this problem leads to a stage table with what you have in excel, then you could have a procedure to convert the name to ID, there would not be out of the box functionality for this.     Or you should have a excel tab with the ID to name match which you could use to do a VLOOKUP to identify ID that needs to be inserted to the database